# count value for each unique id

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

I have a table

```
id    value
1      a
2      a
3      b
4      b
5      b
6      c
```

My id is primary.
I have total 2 a , 3 b and 1 c. So I want to count total repeat value in each primary id which matches on it

I want this format

```
id   value_count
1     2
2     2
3     3
4     3
5     3
6     1
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT a.id, b.valueCnt 
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.value, COUNT(a.value) valueCnt
            FROM tableA a GROUP BY a.value) AS B ON a.value = b.value;
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68a89/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | VALUECNT |
|----|----------|
|  1 |        2 |
|  2 |        2 |
|  3 |        3 |
|  4 |        3 |
|  5 |        3 |
|  6 |        1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
select id, value_count from tablename as a1 
join (select count(*) as value_count, value from tablename group by value) as a2 
on a1.value= a2.value
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a subselect without any joins:

```
SELECT  
a.id,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA WHERE value = a.value) as valueCnt
FROM tableA a
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68a89/4)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use subquery.

```
SELECT table.id , x.value_count
FROM table
INNER JOIN
(SELECT t1.value, count(t1.id) as value_count
FROM table t1
Group by t1.value
) x on x.value = table.value
```